# Request.IsAuthenticated property is returning false with openId Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect

I am integrating Azure AD in my MVC application using openID connect, i follow the steps mentioned in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp

When i hit my application url,  it redirect me to AD and do authentication, i am getting token from 
AD.

But when i check `IsAuthenticated` property in authentication filter, it shows false.

```cs
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```